# Prevent reference from referencing unused depedency

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, xamarin

I have tried searching a solution for this but not sure if I have the correct terms to search on what I need so I have come here to try and solve my issue and get some guidance.

For background, I am currently working on a multi-project .NET solution that contains Xamarin PCL projects (android and iOS), along with a bunch of class libraries, console and GUI applications.

One of the projects is a common shared project/class library compiled as a DLL (lets call it `Common.dll`) that contains a number of common classes/functions to be shared throughout all the projects. For example, an Enum for different error log types that is used throughout all the projects. This project also contains references to EntityFramework (v6 not core) and DbGeography data types.

Now my problem is that my Xamarin.Android project is referencing `Common.dll` and because it has a reference to EntityFramework it is not compiling within Android throwing an error wanting to include a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` for EF which Mono does not have but is required by EntityFramework. However, my Android project does not call any of the EntityFramework functions, classes or types from `Common.dll` so I (wrongly) assumed this would not be an issue.

Given that my `Common.dll` is used extensively and I would like to keep it as is, i.e. a single point to make updates that can be reflected in all the projects, is there a way to not allow it to recursively call for dependencies that are not used in a project?

Or is there a better way to get my Android project to use just the functions it requires from `Common.dll`? I also cannot simply move to EF Core as it does not have all the functionality of EF 6 that I need.

Hopefully that makes some sense, I tried to make diagram below to help illustrate.

```
MySolution
    |
    | -- Common Class Library (Common.dll) - Contains common classes + EntityFramework
    |
    | -- Console App
    |       | -- References Common.dll (uses EF + Enums)
    |
    | -- GUI App
    |       | -- References Common.dll (uses EF + Functions)
    |
    | -- Xamarin.Android (WILL NOT COMPILE)
    |       | -- References Common.dll (uses Functions & Enums only)
    |       |         |
    |       |         | -- Wants to reference System.Configuration for EF
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any easy way out of this so my solution was remove all the Entity Framework and database code out of my common library into a new/separate library project (DLL) that only the required projects will reference.